# Does createrawtransaction have the ability to create a transaction with custom scripts?

Tags: transactions, script

Does `createrawtransaction` always use the following script?

```
scriptPubKey: OP_DUP OP_HASH160 <pubKeyHash> OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
scriptSig: <sig> <pubKey>
```

If so, how do you create a transaction that uses a custom `scriptPubKey` value? If not, what is the syntax for writing the JSON that enables custom scriptPubKey values for the transaction using `createrawtransaction`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is correct.

What you can do is:

- listunspent
- createrawtransaction with receiver:amount and your change:amount

  - (make the amount differ to pay the fee)

Take the raw hex transaction and use it with http://brainwallet.org/#tx to be able to edit in JSON format. Don't worry, when your done you can sign the raw transaction in your local client.

About scriptPubKey, that is a little harder, and you should only experiment with this on testnet. You can try to understand this transaction https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Transaction_puzzle and also try to understand how the stack works by playing around with [jsforth](http://wiki.forthfreak.net/index.cgi?jsforth)

Comment: I have a good idea of how the stack works, and I don't want to use an external site to create my transactions. I'm assuming brainwallet is open source and I can view how they modify the `scriptPubKey` there? There is no way to simply write `{address:amount,scriptPubKey:stuffhere}` in the second field of `createrawtransaction`?

Comment: Also, what does "Yes, that's correct" refer to?

Comment: about createrawtransaction, yes that's correct, it only uses the basic script. about trusting an external site... you dont, its only for convenience... you should always check with **decoderawtransaction** that it will do what you really want

Comment: It's not about trust, I want to learn how to do it myself, I guess at this point the best way is to read the sourcecode of brainwallet and understand how they are doing it. Unless there is documentation somewhere outlining the process.

Comment: brainwallet is only one implementation of how to make a raw transaction, here you can learn about the raw hex and what every bit means https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#tx

Comment: Okay, so I would construct a raw transaction using that specification, then sign it and send it with bitcoind after I am sure the data is correct using `decoderawtransaction`?

Comment: Yes that is exactly right! You can check an already signed transaction with **signrawtransaction** with empty arguments like so [] [], and if all is good it will respond with the same raw transaction and complete:true

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the transaction header. I've dug up some raw transactions I've signed previously with `createrawtransaction` then `signrawtransaction`, I am finding that the first 4 bytes are always the same (as expected). However the next 12 bytes that represent the "tx command" are different. How is that possible? Also, what exactly is the 4 byte payload checksum, and how is it derived?

Comment: The transaction starts with 01 00 00 00, so you dont need to care about how the transaction is broadcasted and how the payload checksum is calculated or [why](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2788/what-are-the-february-20-changes-to-the-bitcoin-protocol)

Comment: Sorry to keep this thread going, but... what do you mean "I don't need to care"? If I'm writing this entire transaction by hand, how do I know what to write for those bits? You're saying I can write anything there and it will be fine? It's extremely frustrating to try to learn this protocol because the documentation is very poor.

Comment: Are you going to create software that can broadcast your transaction to the bitcoin network? If you are, go to the [github](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin) repository. If you will use **sendrawtransaction** from bitcoin-qt or bitcoind, then you do not need to use the Message header.

Comment: Something is very unclear to me: if I can't use `createrawtransaction` to write a transaction with a custom script, how do I build the raw transaction that I eventually sign and broadcast with `sendrawtransaction`?

Comment: Your script need to collect "prev_outputs" that you know you can sign later. Then create a JSON transaction. Convert that JSON to a raw hex transaction and sign it with **signrawtransaction** (or you can write your own code). I found how you can send it with [python](https://github.com/slush0/sendtx)

Comment: I mean, I know how to create a standard raw transaction with `createrawtransaction`, sign it and broadcast it. My question refers to adding custom OPcodes to the `scriptPubKey`, if I can't do that with `createrawtransaction` then how is it done? I want to create this transaction however possible then send it with regular bitcoind.

Comment: **createrawtransaction** is only a first step, to be able to play around with transactions. I don't think they will ever add the ability to do custom OPcodes. I want the same thing, make transactions by code, but I dont know how. Ask at [bitcointalk](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?board=39.0)

Answer (score 0):

After reading: https://bitcoindev.network/guides/bitcoinjs-lib/bitcoin-script-puzzles/ and reverting versions of some libraries I think I managed it with https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib Unfortunately the transaction wasn't accepted by the network, possibly because non-standard? Not sure. One day I'll debug it.

main.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// inputs
from_txid = '0f2084be761e258f9bdb00d546b44a173cc31951a7f8d1f64b63c4c5da73cdb4'
from_vout = 0
to_ammount = 63800

to_addr = '3KRk7f2JgekF6x7QBqPHdZ3pPDuMdY3eWR'
to_ammount = 63800
// https://bitcoinfees.gitlab.io/
to_fee = 27 * 255
to_net = to_ammount - to_fee

const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib')
const network = bitcoin.networks.bitcoin
const redeemScript = bitcoin.script.compile([
  bitcoin.opcodes.OP_ADD,
  bitcoin.opcodes.OP_5,
  bitcoin.opcodes.OP_EQUAL])
const p2wpkhAlice0 = bitcoin.payments.p2sh({ address: to_addr, network })
const txb = new bitcoin.TransactionBuilder(network)
txb.addInput(from_txid, from_vout)
txb.addOutput(p2wpkhAlice0.address, to_net)
console.error('p2wpkhAlice0.address: ' + require('util').inspect(p2wpkhAlice0.address));
const tx = txb.buildIncomplete()
const InputScriptP2SH = bitcoin.script.compile([bitcoin.opcodes.OP_2, bitcoin.opcodes.OP_3])
tx.setInputScript(0, InputScriptP2SH)
console.log(tx.toHex())
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tmp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "AGPL",
  "dependencies": {
    "bip32": "2.0.6",
    "bip39": "2.6.0",
    "bitcoinjs-lib": "5.2.0"
  }
}
```

You have to use these versions of libraries with that code because interfaces changed a lot.

main.js produces a hex raw transaction which you can then try to submit with:

```
bitcoin-cli sendrawtransaction <hex>
```